# What is JSON-RPC and do i need it?

Tags: client, json-rpc, mining-setup

I have recently finished installing the Bitcoin client. One site i was using to help guide me is called http://www.weusecoins.com/en/. On the mining guide section of that site it says, If you're mining on your own you need to start by setting up your Bitcoin client and set it up for JSON-RPC. I was trying to figure out what it is and how to set it up if i need it but i could not figure it out. My questions then are what is JSON-RPC and do i need it ? Is it set up by default in the original Bitcoin client ?

Comment: To answer your questions in order: Only to mine or automate payments; no.

Comment: Are you saying no its not needed or no its not set up by default ? If i need it to mine how do i enable it ?

Comment: You need to set up the bitcoin.conf file for it to work. You also need to make sure you allow Json-rpc commands in the .conf file. You can find a sample configuration file here:https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Sample_Bitcoin.conf. YOu dont need it to mine. Only if you are trying to use bitcoin data on your own site or for your custom fpga miner or something along those lines

Comment: You mentioned it could be needed for custom FPGA. What about for an ASIC from butterfly labs when it ships ?

Answer (score 5):

The [JSON-RPC](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29#JSON-RPC) interface is a way for other programs to interact with Bitcoin-Qt or `bitcoind` while it's running. It's useful for doing things like mining or building a web site that needs to talk to the Bitcoin network directly. Most users don't need to worry about it or set it up.

Comment: Useful to miners you say ? Will i need this for an ASIC ?

Comment: You may, if you want to solo mine (I wouldn't advise that). Otherwise, no.

Comment: Why would you not advise solo mining ? Also how would i know if i need it or not while solo mining ?

Comment: You will need it for solo mining. I don't advise solo mining because of the inconsistency of return. You could solo mine for months or years and not see a return.